# LOOP When scraping with python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

i am trying to scrap data using python with this simple code

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=fais&type=2&limit=100"
r = requests.get(url)
cont = json.loads(r.content)
print(cont)
```

the output of the code : JSON

```
[{u'phone': u'99399934', u'name': u'fai'}, {u'phone': u'99111267', u'name': u'Fai2 Basheer '}, {u'phone': u'50129494', u'name': u'Fai4 Delly '}]
```

it works great for me but the problem is a need a loop so i can send multiple requests with different parameter for EXAMPLE :

```
https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=JOHN&type=2&limit=6000"
https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=SAM&type=2&limit=9000"
https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=JOHN&type=2&limit=1000"
https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=HARRY&type=2&limit=7000"
```

because every different limit parameter value scrap new data from the same keyword because the json request returns only 1000Row.

Comment: Make a list of urls and then do `for url in urls:`, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Approach**:

using a `list` of urls, and then iterate over it to get the response of each.

```
urls = ['https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=JOHN&type=2&limit=6000"',
'https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=SAM&type=2&limit=9000"',
'https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=JOHN&type=2&limit=1000"',
'https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=HARRY&type=2&limit=7000"']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    cont = json.loads(r.content)
    print(cont)
```

**Second Approach**:

A nested `dict` that holds all the parameters:

```
data = {
'data_1' : {'keyword': 'JOHN', 'type': '2', 'limit': '6000'},
'data_2' : {'keyword': 'SAM', 'type': '2', 'limit': '2000'},
'data_3' : {'keyword': 'JOHN', 'type': '2', 'limit': '1000'},
'data_4' : {'keyword': 'HARRY', 'type': '2', 'limit': '7000'}
}

for param in data:
    page = requests.get("https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?", params=data[param])
    cont = json.loads(r.content)
    print(cont)
```

Comment: @Austin Uh, I guess I took a long Lunch break. Added! :)

Comment: Great works for me , how i can save the scraped data into a text file or CSV file please

Comment: @J.Fredy that should be asked in a different question, you may accept the answer by clicking on the tick sign beside it if it helped and post another question with your new requirements and would love to answer! cheers

Comment: here is my other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945744/how-to-save-scraped-json-data-to-csv-or-text-file

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters = [
'JOHN:6000',
'SAM:9000',
'JOHN:1000',
'HARRY:7000']



import requests
import json


for item in parameters:
    key, value = item.split(':')
    url = "https://xxxxxxxx.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=%s&type=2&limit=%s" %(key, value)
    r = requests.get(url)
    cont = json.loads(r.content)
    print(cont)
```

Comment: Not really. One is JOHN and 6000, next is JOHN and 1000. Also this fails as dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. :P

Comment: ah yes, missed that, my bad. I was jumping the gun. Also it was originally the same, he edited it.