# How to Save Scraped Json Data to CSV or Text File

Tags: python, web-scraping

i need to know how to save scraped data into a csv file this is the code

```
import requests
import json

parameters = ['a:1','a:2','a:3','a:4','a:3','a:4','a:5','a:6','a:7','a:8','a:9','a:10',]

for item in parameters:
    key, value = item.split(':')[0], item.split(':')[1]
    url = "https://xxxx.000webhostapp.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=%s&type=2&limit=%s" %(key, value)
    r = requests.get(url)
    cont = json.loads(r.content)
    print(cont)
```

AND THE OUTPUT BE LIKE

```
[{'name': 'Absz', 'phone': '66343212'}, {'name': 'ddd ', 'phone': '545432211'}, {'name': 'ezd' 'phone':'54856886'}]
```

I want to store all data in `CSV` File or Text File

How i can do this ?

Comment: Check [this](http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-json-to-csv-using-python/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather simple task.
Did you not try to search this, as there are an abundance of examples of turning a dictionary into a csv file?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

parameters = ['a:1','a:2','a:3','a:4','a:3','a:4','a:5','a:6','a:7','a:8','a:9','a:10']

results = pd.DataFrame()
for item in parameters:
    key, value = item.split(':')
    url = "https://xxxx.000webhostapp.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=%s&type=2&limit=%s" %(key, value)
    try:        
        r = requests.get(url)
        cont = json.loads(r.content)
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(cont)

        results = results.append(temp_df)
    except:
        continue

results.to_csv('path/to/filename.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thank you but i need to save the data from the link directly to a csv or text file can you help me with that as i explain in my question ?
Thank you

Comment: do you need 1 final csv file? or a csv file for each link?

Comment: i need one csv file contains all the data

Comment: when i'm using more than 3 parameters i get this error please help : raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: the full error code after using more than 3 parametrs : https://pastebin.com/1b22sJ3c

Comment: that means when it gets to this part, `cont = json.loads(r.content)`, the r variable is not returning anything.

Comment: what i have to do ?

Comment: i put in a `try except`. if it gets to a parameter that doesnt return a json, it'll move on to the next parameter